# Why does paramaterless constructor need to be defined when using Activator.CreateInstance?

Tags: c#, .net

When using this

```
Activator.CreateInstance()
```

in this function

```
    public static List<IType> GetTypeList()
    {
        List<IType> types = new List<IType>();
        types.AddRange(from assembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                       from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                       where t.IsClass && t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IType))
                       select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as IType);

        return types;
    }
```

If in each of my classes that implement IType if I define a constructor that takes parameters but don't explicitly write the default constructor it complains

***MissingMethodException was unhandled
"No parameterless constructor defined for this object."***

but when I remove all constructors, it works fine, no errors even though I also didn't explicitly write the default constructor.

I thought that the default parameterless  constructor was always there even if you didn't define it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I thought that the default parameterless constructor was always there even if you didn't define it

Not true. If you explicitly define *any* constructor, the compiler will no longer provide a default no-argument one for you.

Note, though, that you *can* instantiate a type that does not have a no-argument constructor. Just use the [Activator.CreateInstance() overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wcxyzt4d) that takes an array of parameters. For example, if the constructor takes two `int`s, and pass the values 42 and 123:

```
MyClass obj = (MyClass) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass), 42, 123);
```

You can also use the reflection API directly:

```
var type = typeof(MyClass);
var ctor = type.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(int), typeof(int) });
MyClass obj = (MyClass) ctor.Invoke(new object[] { 42, 123 });
```

See [Type.GetConstructor()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/h93ya84h) and [ConstructorInfo.Invoke()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6ycw1y17) on MSDN.

Comment: +1. you can also use [CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that passes arguments to constructor.

Comment: Actually you can do `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(MyClass), 42, 123);`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks, was just adding that myself :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to create an object without calling the constructor (like when de-serializing), I would suggest doing what the CLR does and using [FormatterServices.GetUnitializedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatterservices.getuninitializedobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  Although this satisfies the requirement of not needing the object to have a paramless constructor, it could cause unintended side effects if not used with discretion.

Otherwise you need to use parameterless constructors and/or modify your code to handle arguments.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. The OP almost certainly does not want to do this!

Comment: giving options, not making assumptions about what the OP is trying to do.  As I mention it can have unintended side effects.  Given the code sample I can't see how the OP would be able to call the constructors appropriately, can you?

Comment: +1. @TypeIA - I believe it is a valid approach for possible use case and generally interesting piece of information. While you may be right that OP does not need that it is unclear what actual OP's goal is and if it is custom serialization this solution very well could work. There are also enough warnings in MSDN article.

Comment: Yes, using any of the other methods presented. In the sample code he posted he is creating new objects, not doing something with low-level deserialization. Given that, GetUninitializedObject() is absolutely, positively, objectively, not a valid solution.

Comment: I'm sorry that you disagree, but I believe you are be presumptuous given the OP's information.  I believe this could be precisely what is being asked.